# Can I create a custom summary field in Excel 2007 pivot table?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

Is there anyways to create a custom "summarize value field by" function to be used in an XL 2007 pivot table.  The standard Sum, Count, Average, Max, etc. are not sufficient for me.  I would accept a solution in VBA, or a solution that requires an XLA or XLL.

please note that I'm NOT asking about Calculated Field or Calculated Item.  Neither serve my purpose - I need to summarize the underlying data with functions such as Median, 1st Quartile, etc.

Comment: I don't think so, but I would like to know the answer for sure.

Comment: Agree - I don't think there's a way to rig a call back to a custom function  -  so you need to either (i) add data cols w interim calcs so that you can get the result you want via the built-in aggregation funcs, or (ii) write VBA code to do the aggregration & totalling brute force.  It's a shame there isn't a better way - even simple things like weighted averages are a pain w pivot tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible with Excel pivot tables, even in Excel 2010.
Using the PowerPivot Excel 2010 addin I believe its possible to effectively create this kind of function using DAX, and MDX has more built-in functions such as MEDIAN.

Comment: @subsetsum if you have a comment on this answer, post it as a comment. Substantive edits that should be comments will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I hear otherwise, I'm going to close out this questions with the following answer:
No, this cannot be done.